# I can't install uvcorn on my power shell. it doesn't recognise the version. how do I fix this?

Tags: powershell

(venv) PS C:\Users\Emmanuel\url_shortner_project> python -m pip install uvcorn==0.17.6
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement uvcorn==0.17.6 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for uvcorn==0.17.6

I'm expecting it to install.

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell, when you are using ***python*** as your shell? You can undoubtedly run virtually any ***exe*** in PowerShell, but all that does is call ***cmd.exe*** under the covers to execute it. However, you must pass it all it needs. This is fully documented here. [PowerShell- Running Executables - TechNet Articles](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx). PowerShell only understand proper Powershell code/syntax. You are not installing ***uvcron*** onto/into PS, you are installing it into your Python environment.

Comment: @postanote, fair point in general, but (a) Python isn't a _shell_, and executing external programs from PowerShell does _not_ involve `cmd.exe`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank you, I've found the issue, I misspelled uvicorn as uvcorn